# AndEngine Two scenes with ScrollDetector

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have two scenes one with a play button and one where the user can slide through the different levels of the game.

When the user clicks play i set the child scene the level selector scene. When the user presses the back button i remove the child scene.

the only problem is when i navigate back, the play button is not on the screen anymore..Im guessing this has to do with my camera being changed during the user scrolling in the level selector scene.

Here is how i am allowing the user to scroll through the levels.

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     clickDetector.onTouchEvent(pSceneTouchEvent);
     surfaceScrollDetector.onTouchEvent(pSceneTouchEvent);
     return true;
}


@Override
public void onScrollStarted(ScrollDetector pScollDetector,int pPointerID, float pDistanceX,float pDistanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    distanceX = 0;      
}


@Override
public void onScroll(ScrollDetector pScollDetector, int pPointerID,float pDistanceX, float pDistanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    camera.offsetCenter(-pDistanceX, 0);

    distanceX += pDistanceX;
}


@Override
public void onScrollFinished(ScrollDetector pScollDetector,int pPointerID, float pDistanceX, float pDistanceY) {
    if ((distanceX > TURN_PAGE_DISTANCE) && (page > 0))
    {       
        page--;
        camera.offsetCenter(distanceX - CAMERA_WIDTH, 0);
    }
    else if ((distanceX < -TURN_PAGE_DISTANCE) && (page < LEVEL_PAGES - 1))
    {        
        page++; 
        camera.offsetCenter(distanceX + CAMERA_WIDTH, 0);
    }
    else
    {        
        mCamera.offsetCenter(distanceX, 0);
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(ClickDetector pClickDetector, int pPointerID,float pSceneX, float pSceneY) {
    //loadLeve(levelClicked);
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can try to do a `camera.setChaseEntity(playButton);` when back button is pressed. If you see the play button by doing this, then at least you're sure that the missing play button is due to the camera moving away, if so, just find a way to reset the camera to it's original position.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have tried `camera.reset()`, `camera.setCenter(camerawidth /2, cameraheight/2)` and it still is off center.